# При создании симуляции работы банка, хэшмап не сохраняет имена

Tags: java, null, java-hashmap

При создании банка я хотел чтоб каждому пользователю давался случайный ID, который в дальнейшем будет использоваться как ключ для поиска его имени и дальнейших действий, но при удалении пользователя по ключу, он пишет что его имя null, а при создании ему же депозита и вовсе выдаёт ошибку, помогите пожалуйста

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class bank {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Simulation start = new Simulation();
    start.listStart();
    }
}


    class Users{
        HashMap<Integer, String> idAndClients = new HashMap<>(); // поля данных
        private final ArrayList<Integer> listId = new ArrayList<>(); // список имеющихся айди для сравнение
        private final HashMap<Integer, depositAction> action = new HashMap<>();

        public int randIdAdd(String name){
            System.out.println("Операция добавления пользователя:");
            Random random = new Random();
            int id;
            id=random.nextInt(10000);
            for (int i = 0; i < listId.size(); i++) {
              if(id==listId.get(i)){
                  id=random.nextInt(10000);
                  i--;
              }
            }
            listId.add(id);
            idAndClients.put(id,name);
            action.put(id, new depositAction());
            System.out.println("Пользователь: "+idAndClients.get(id)+" ID: "+ id);
            System.out.println("....................успешно");
            System.out.println();

            return id;
        }

        public void deleteUser(int index){
            System.out.println("Операция удаления пользователя:");
            System.out.println("Пользователь: "+idAndClients.get(index)+" ID: "+ index);
            idAndClients.remove(index);
            action.remove(index);
            System.out.println("....................успешно");
            System.out.println();
        }

        public void takeOn(int id, int depIndex){ //Создаем массив депозитов для отедьного пользователя для пополнения
            depositAction d = action.get(id);
            d.takeOnMoney(depIndex);
        }

        public void takeOff(int id, int depIndex){
            depositAction d = action.get(id);
            d.takeOffMoney(depIndex);
        }

        public void createDep(int id, int dep){
            System.out.println("Операция  по созданию депозитов:");
            System.out.println("Пользователь: "+idAndClients.get(id)+" ID: "+ id + "требует создания "+(dep+1)+" депозитов");
            depositAction d = action.get(id);
            d.addDeposit(dep);
        }

        public void deleteDep(int id){
            depositAction d = action.get(id);
            d.deleteDeposit();
        }

    }

    class depositAction extends Currency{
        private final ArrayList<Integer> deposits = new ArrayList<>(); //Список депозитов пользователя
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        public void addDeposit(int dep) {
            if (dep <= 4) {
                for (int i = 0; i < dep; i++) {
                    deposits.add(0);
                }
                System.out.println("....................успешно");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Пользователь требует создание более 5 депозитов");
            }
        }

        public void deleteDeposit(){
            System.out.println("Какой депозит удалить?");
            int quantity = scanner.nextInt();
            if (deposits.size() < quantity || deposits.get(quantity)==null) {
                System.out.println("Данный депозит отсутствует");
            }
            else{
            deposits.remove(quantity);
            System.out.println(quantity + "депозит был удалён");}
        }

        public void takeOnMoney(int indexDeposit) {
            indexDeposit -= 1;
            if (deposits.size() > indexDeposit) {
                System.out.println("Доступные купюры : 1, 5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000");
                System.out.print("На сколько пополнить " + indexDeposit + " депозит?:");
                int cash = scanner.nextInt();
                    cash += deposits.get(indexDeposit);
                    deposits.set(indexDeposit, cash);
                    System.out.println("На вашем счету:" + deposits.get(indexDeposit));
                }

            else{
                    System.out.println("Такого депозита нет");

                }
            }

        public void takeOffMoney(int indexDeposit){
            indexDeposit -= 1;
            if (deposits.size() > indexDeposit) {
                System.out.println("Доступные купюры : 1, 5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000");
                System.out.print("Сколько денежных средств снять с " +indexDeposit + " депозита?");
                int cash = scanner.nextInt();
                    int timeCash=cash;
                    while (timeCash!=0){
                    if((timeCash/1000)>0){
                        timeCash-=1000;
                        valuesCurrency[6]-=1;
                    }
                    else if((timeCash/500)>0){
                        timeCash-=500;
                        valuesCurrency[5]-=1;
                    }
                    else if((timeCash/100)>0){
                        timeCash-=100;
                        valuesCurrency[4]-=1;
                    }
                    else if((timeCash/50)>0){
                        timeCash-=50;
                        valuesCurrency[3]-=1;
                    }
                    else if((timeCash/10)>0){
                        timeCash-=10;
                        valuesCurrency[2]-=1;
                    }
                    else if((timeCash/5)>0){
                        timeCash-=5;
                        valuesCurrency[1]-=1;
                    }
                    else{
                        timeCash-=1;
                        valuesCurrency[0]-=1;
                    }
                        if(valuesCurrency[0]<0 ||
                            valuesCurrency[1]<0 ||
                            valuesCurrency[2]<0 ||
                            valuesCurrency[3]<0 ||
                            valuesCurrency[4]<0 ||
                            valuesCurrency[5]<0 ||
                            valuesCurrency[6]<0){
                    addBankMoney();
                    }
                    }
                    cash = deposits.get(indexDeposit)-cash;
                    deposits.set(indexDeposit, cash);
                    System.out.println("На вашем счету:" + deposits.get(indexDeposit));
                System.out.println("Наличие купюр банка:");
                    for (int i = 0; i <num.length; i++) {
                        System.out.println(valuesCurrency[i]);
                    }
                }

            else {
                System.out.println("Данный депозит отсутствует");
            }
        }
     }

     class Currency{

    public int[] num = {1, 5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000};
    public int[] valuesCurrency= {
            1000000000,
            100000000,
            10000000,
            1000000,
            100000,
            10000,
            1000
    };
         public void addBankMoney(){ // Если закончилась какая то валюта пополнить её
             for (int i = 0; i <valuesCurrency.length; i++) {
                 valuesCurrency[i]+=1000;
             }
         }

     }

    class Simulation {

        public void listStart() {
            Users go = new Users();
            Random random = new Random();
            Users actions = new Users();
            ArrayList<Integer> idList = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> possibleUsers = new ArrayList<>();
            idList.add(actions.randIdAdd("Экремика"));
            idList.add(actions.randIdAdd("Катя Самбука"));
            idList.add(actions.randIdAdd("Сказачное Бали"));
            idList.add(actions.randIdAdd("Фифти-Фифти"));
            idList.add(actions.randIdAdd("Чебурек"));
            idList.add(actions.randIdAdd("Дырчик"));
            idList.add(actions.randIdAdd("Сивый"));

            possibleUsers.add("Мегатрон");
            possibleUsers.add("Набор лего космонавты");
            possibleUsers.add("Спинер");
            possibleUsers.add("Сок 'Красавчик'");
            possibleUsers.add("Телепузик");
            possibleUsers.add("Мама");

            for (int i = 0; i < 24 * 365; i += random.nextInt(120) + 1) {
                int selection = random.nextInt(8);
                if(selection==1){
                    go.randIdAdd(possibleUsers.get(random.nextInt(6)));

                }
                else if(selection==2){
                    go.deleteUser(idList.get(random.nextInt(idList.size())));
                }
                else if(selection==3){
                    go.createDep(idList.get(random.nextInt(idList.size())),random.nextInt(6));
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ваш метод генерации id нерабочий. И вы походу не понимаете, зачем нужен HashMap (иначе бы избавились от листа с id). Дальше читать не стал - сократите ваш пример до минимального кода, чтобы читатели не тратили время на чтение всего полотна.

Comment: поглядел чуть дальше ваш код. Обратите внимание на эту строку `go.createDep(idList.get(random.nextInt(idList.size())),random.nextInt(6));` - вы походу не понимаете, что если взять просто какое то число в одном списке и попробовать искать его в другом - то можно ничего и не найти, учитывая, что списки между собой не связаны никак.